# SQL Output as XML namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am new to XML so please forgive my ignorance.

I have the below SQL statement that forms part of a XML output:

```
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.example.com' as ns)
SELECT 
    @XMLOutput = (blah blah blah
                  FOR XML PATH('Job'), TYPE, ROOT('JobLoader')
                 )


SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT   (NVARCHAR(MAX), @XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```

However, how do I amend so it outputs the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JobLoader xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: Your example doesn't actually run, which makes it hard to identify what the problem is, but you may be looking for `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.example.com')`.

Comment: and perhaps `WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,DEFAULT 'http://www.example.com')` if you want both

Comment: Your example is more or less "pseudo code" because of the blah blah blah part, what are you trying to do here? Are you trying to generate a XML from table data or generate a XML on the fly ? see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) if tables should be involved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi,
                   DEFAULT 'http://www.example.com'
                    )
SELECT 
    @XMLOutput = (SELECT *
                  FROM dbo.PhoneDataTest
                  FOR XML PATH('Job'), TYPE, ROOT('JobLoader')
                 )


SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT   (NVARCHAR(MAX), @XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```